# how do traffic move when there's roadblock by police

Tags: crime, police, people

Imagine there is a gun shooting incident so police will obviously control traffic but then how do people react when road is blocked? do they wait on block to know what is happening or do they just go around?

If you find any resource to see how people react, you can let me know.

Comment: You are asking a question about the real world. Worldbuilding is for imaginary worlds.

Answer (score 2):

**Close the Section of Road**

The police usually close the section of road where the accident happened. For example if there is a crash on Woodbridge Street (marked in red) the first move is to close the whole section and put signs and roadblocks at both ends.

[image]

That means there is no trouble with cars piling up near the crash site and not being able to turn around.

It also means you can investigate the whole section for skid-marks, bullet holes, pieces of broken car engine, butterfly testicles, and anything else that might be relevant to the crime, without other cars disturbing the evidence.

Once the site is fully investigated, the police might open a single lane of traffic on the road, that goes around the crash site, with a traffic guard who alternates which direction gets to use the lane.

In both cases, drivers tend to comply with the roadblocks and traffic guard.

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps tells them there is a road block and redirects the driver.

Additionally, I've seen police redirect traffic. (Usually due to bad wrecks or a house on fire)

Some people will wait. (Large trucks that can't turn around). Others will turn around (even without police asking them to)

This is a common-sense thing.  It happens (wrecks that blocks a road) at least 2x a year to me. Gun fights shouldn't be too much different. (If you check the news, you'd hear them mention that the road was blocked because of the standoff)

I really hope you aren't trying to plan something nefarious IRL.

Comment: Thought of applying realistic behavior for making a game. But I thought of someone just rushing into block out of ordinary so that might be cool to add. But also thought if I keep adding imaginary then it will just be a mess so decided not to and just follow nature. Wait but someone can rush into block if they have reason but anyways

Comment: That info would be useful in your question. Please edit your question and add it. (Then I can adjust my answer to fit your needs)

Comment: I don't have a Google Maps in my car.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that there are national differences in play.

The initial reaction is most likely a police car, with flashing lights, physically blocking some or all of the road. Motorists who try to bypass this makeshift roadblock get yelled at. If the cause is an accident rather than a crime, the initial block might be a fire engine, but again the police would be dispatched if traffic is thought to become problematic.

Meanwhile, motorists are piling up. Some motorists try to back out of the temporary dead-end street while others try to enter. Any motorists who make it to the roadblock might be told by the police "sorry, this might take some time" but likely not the details. A cop on the street is no press spokesperson for the department.

If the police imply that this is a temporary inconvenience, motorists might stop their car rather than seeking a detour. They might also pull out their smartphone to take [pictures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubbernecking) for 'social' media, but various countries discourage this more or less emphatically.

This would be different if there is an active *shooting* incident. Anybody within a mile would be at risk from stray bullets. (Pistol bullets remain deadly much longer than they can be aimed.) The police would urgently tell people to get away and to get under cover.

The next step would be what [Daron](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/221184/how-do-traffic-move-when-theres-roadblock-by-police/221191#221191) mentioned -- a deliberate block at a suitable intersection, perhaps quizzing motorists and letting some pass who have a legitimate reason to be on that road. "You can drive to your property, but no further than that."

If this goes on for some time, navigation apps will learn. Either users actively [report](https://www.blog.google/products/maps/new-ways-report-driving-incidents-google-maps/) it, or the servers notice that nobody is passing a certain point.